# Asp.Net MVC 5 Template: BundleCollection script missing - returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, visual-studio-2013

After Creating [an MVC-Project from a tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and pressing F5 in Visual Studio 2013 Express Web i get a wrong Script reference and a `500 Internal Server Error`

- The page is hosted on `http://localhost:1874`
- 3 Scripts (jquery, modernizer and bootstrap are working fine
- but there is a 4th Script-Reference that seems to appear out of nowhere and which uses "the wrong port" `1563` and points to a nonexisting path `http://localhost:1563/e85db51b515e433384e40d2dd8b28559`.

This is my BundleConfig

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css"));
    }
}
```

Where does this 4th. reference come from?
How can i fix the port and file path?

#### Chrome Dev-Tools - Headers output

The get looks like this:

```
GET /e85db51b515e433384e40d2dd8b28559 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:1563
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.57 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://localhost:1874/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en,en-US;q=0.8,de;q=0.6,de-DE;q=0.4
```

And the Response Headers like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Content-Length: 0
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Mon, 02 Dec 2013 23:00:58 GMT
```

#### What is unclear?

What i still do not know is how to fix the port of the browser link?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Visual Studio [Browser Link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/01/10430221.aspx)

In the generated Page the culprit seems to be these lines:

```
<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"8cec45910def4767bfb3087ff70084cf"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:1563/e85db51b515e433384e40d2dd8b28559" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->
```

Adding this to the webconfig removed the [browser link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/01/10430221.aspx)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
```

Comment: I'm glad I was able to remove the visual studio browser link, but it hasn't helped my problem, unfortunately :(